# mv complains about standard input in a pipeline that filters file name with grep

Tags: shell-script, find, grep, rename

I'm trying to move several .avi files that have spaces in from a CD to my home folder. I've already know how to get rid of the spaces:

```
find /media/mathscd/ | grep -L -r "*.avi" | for file in *; do mv "$file" echo $file | tr ' ' '_' ; done
```

But I'm struggling to get move to find the edited files and move them en masse into the folder. I keep getting the error `mv: cannot stat '(standard input)': No such file or directory`. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
find /media/mathscd/ | grep -L -r  "*.avi" | xargs -I{} mv {} /home/09murphyt/Downloads/
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What kind of files is your `grep` trying to match?

Comment: What happens if you enclose `{}` in quotes, i.e. mv `"{}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `-L` switch to `grep`.
From the man page:

> L, --files-without-match
>  
>      Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
>      file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
>      scanning will stop on the first match.

So instead of listing the *file names* that do not match `avi` it only lists the *place* where `grep` didn't find `avi`. Since `grep` usually looks in a file, such a switch would list file names not containing the pattern `avi` within them. In your case, however, since you're piping to `grep` from `find`, the file that `grep` is reading is `(standard input)`. To see what I mean, try:

```
find /media/mathscd | grep -L "*.avi"
```

result:

```
(standard input)
```

In other words, `grep` found lines not matching `"*.avi"` on standard input, which is exactly what happened.

Since `find` lists file names directly, you only need to invert the sense of the match:

```
find /media/mathscd | grep -v ".*\.avi"
```

(note that `grep` patterns are different from shell wildcards; you also don't need the `-r` switch)

Also, using `find` alone:

```
find /media/mathscd ! -name "*.avi"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

```
find /media/mathscd/ -name *.avi -exec mv -t ~/Downloads/ {} +
find /media/mathscd/ -name *.avi -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Downloads/
```

Make sure to test it by replacing `xargs mv*` with `xargs ls` first.